# How to access folder named "x y" (x space y) using Ubuntu Bash script in Windows?

Tags: bash

I am using Bash script. When I run `cd x y`, I get an error that x is not a directory. However, files having names without spaces are selected.

Answer (score 2):

Either quote your argument:

```
cd "x y"
```

or escape (make not special) the space:

```
cd x\ y
```